# Image Processing on CUDA or OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, cuda

I need to develop an image processing program for my project in which I have to count the number of cars on the road. I am using GPU programming. Should I go for OpenCV program with GPU processing feature or should I develop my entire program on CUDA without any OpenCV library?

The algorithms which I am using for counting the number of cars is background subtraction, segmentation and edge detection.

Answer (score 6):

You can use GPU functions in OpenCV.

First visit the introduction about this : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/introduction.html

Secondly, I think above mentioned processes are already implemented in OpenCV optimized for GPU. So It will be much easier to develop with OpenCV.

Canny Edge Detection : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html#gpu-canny

PerElement Operations (including subtraction): http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/per_element_operations.html#per-element-operations

For other functions, visit OpenCV docs.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV, no doubt, has the biggest collection of Image processing functionality and recently they've started porting functions to CUDA as well. There's a new GPU module in latest OpenCV with few functions ported to CUDA.

Being said that, OpenCV is not the best option to build a CUDA based application as there are many dedicated CUDA libraries like [CUVI](http://cuvilib.com/) that [beat OpenCV in Performance](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2012/05/17/cuvi-is-faster-than-opencv-gpu/). If you're looking for an optimized solution, you should also give them a try.

Comment: Can you provide some link to the tutorials/ examples using CUVI.